# Not able to load a project of VS2012 in VS2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-7.8

i got a project for mobile application which is created in Visual studio 2012,but when i am trying to run it in VS2013,it is showing some error in **csproj**.How to find which thing is missing like any SDK or service packs. CSPROJ file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <CurrentDeployCmdId>256</CurrentDeployCmdId>
    <CurrentDeployID>3B750D6D-6343-41bd-8FD5-18F53DF36A6F</CurrentDeployID>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'">
    <CurrentDeployCmdId>256</CurrentDeployCmdId>
    <CurrentDeployID>3B750D6D-6343-41bd-8FD5-18F53DF36A6F</CurrentDeployID>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectView>ProjectFiles</ProjectView>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{C089C8C0-30E0-4E22-80C0-CE093F111A43}">
        <SilverlightMobileCSProjectFlavor>
          <FullDeploy>False</FullDeploy>
          <DebuggerType>Managed</DebuggerType>
          <DebuggerAgentType>Managed</DebuggerAgentType>
          <Tombstone>False</Tombstone>
        </SilverlightMobileCSProjectFlavor>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
</Project>
```

and the error report is 
[image]

Comment: plz see the attched screenshot..thanks

Comment: Please edit your post and type in the error, since your image isn't working

Comment: What did the link in the error tell you>

Comment: Clicking on error link showing nothing,but the message below is-- The application which this project type is based on was not found

Comment: i think windows phonw SDK has not installed on my system.I have taken this project from some other guy.So i am not sure which version of WIndows SDK he was using.Could u guys tell me why this tag is being used in csproj-SilverlightMobileCSProjectFlavor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the [link in the error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh266747(v=vs.120).aspx), which points you to a page called 'Visual Studio 2013 Compatibility', telling you:

> Windows Mobile
>
> This project can't be opened in Visual Studio 2013 because it doesn't support the project type.

So you should continue to use Visual Studio 2012 in order to develop your Windows Mobile app.